# Does moving an element from an STL container remove it from that container?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, stl, move-semantics

I have a `Foobar` class with a `sayHello()` method that outputs "Well hello there!". If I write the following code

```
vector<unique_ptr<Foobar>> fooList;
fooList.emplace_back(new Foobar());

unique_ptr<Foobar> myFoo = move(fooList[0]);
unique_ptr<Foobar> myFoo2 = move(fooList[0]);
myFoo->sayHello();
myFoo2->sayHello();

cout << "vector size: " << fooList.size() << endl;
```

The output is:

```
Well hello there!
Well hello there!
vector size: 1
```

I'm confused why this works. Shouldn't `fooList[0]` become null when I do the first move? Why does `myFoo2` work?

Here's what `Foobar` looks like:

```
class Foobar
{
public:
    Foobar(void) {};
    virtual ~Foobar(void) {};

    void sayHello() const {
        cout << "Well hello there!" << endl; 
    };
};
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Shouldn't fooList[0] become null when I do the first move?

Yes.

> Why does myFoo2 work?

It doesn't; it causes undefined behaviour. Your compiler happens to produce code that doesn't crash if you use a null pointer to call a non-virtual function that doesn't dereference `this`.

If you change the function as follows, it will be clearer what's happening:

```
void sayHello() const {
    cout << "Well hello there! My address is " << this << endl; 
}

Well hello there! My address is 0x1790010
Well hello there! My address is 0
vector size: 1
```

Comment: Ah-hah! That suddenly makes a lot of sense. The vector still says size 1, but it's just a unique_ptr to `nullptr` now and will get cleaned up when the vector goes out of scope like I'm hoping. Looks like everything is working as I expected, my compiler as you pointed out is just playing tricks on me. Thanks!

Comment: I added a data member to `Foobar` and access it in `sayHello()`. Now the code crashes as I would expect when trying to use `myFoo2`.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is: No, move operations doesn't remove elements from containers.

Another comment: the use of the emplace_back function is likely to be inadequate.

try:

```
vector<unique_ptr<Foobar>> fooList;
fooList.emplace_back( new Foobar );
```

Comment: @Mike Seymour has clarified that move() will in fact move the object out of the vector, but a zeroed `unique_ptr` will remain in the vector. Also, thanks for pointing out the change for my `emplace_back` call. Your example compiles and runs fine, I believe it avoids an additional constructor.

Comment: I've edited my original question to reflect your correction in case someone in the future stumbles on the code.

Comment: I wanted to highlight the item will persist inside the vector.